# Why does net/http handler not process multiple requests concurently?

Tags: http, go, concurrency

I created a small test server in order to test what happens in a handler.  Here's what it looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

)

func HelloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("HIT HANDLER")
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("FINISHED")
}


func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", HelloHandler)

    fmt.Printf("Starting server at port 8080\n")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

The second "HIT HANDLER" will only log out *after* the first time.Sleep has finished.
Why is that?  Why is this behaving synchronously?
Are the two requests hitting the same exact function in memory?
How do companies handle this issue at scale? Suppose someone is trying to hit a login handler and while the process for logging them in is happening, someone else hits that same handler?

Comment: "Are the two requests hitting the same exact function in memory?" -- Yes, of course they are. But that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Your code does not behave as you describe.  When I run it, I get "HIT HANDLER" immediately for every request I make. However, if you're trying to run multiple tests simultaneously from the same shell, i.e. by running `curl`, in a loop, then you'll observe what you describe, because the client is running syncronously.

Comment: There is no any issue at all, every request processed in own goroutine, the function is the same arguments different.

Comment: So just to clarify, both of these requests are "inside" the same area of memory (the handler) at the same time?  Since I'm executing the requests right after each other but sleeping them to make them take longer.

Comment: "inside the same area of memory" is a confused/meaningless statement in this context. They both execute the exact same function in memory yes. But each one has its own call stack, etc.

Comment: @Flimzy im making the requests from the browser.

Comment: @nightly: Make multiple requests in different browsers/windows/tabs.

Comment: @Flimzy if each has its own call stack then why wouldn't the two calls execute the handler right away? Why is one request waiting for the other to finish.  Call being made from browser.

Comment: They do both execute right away. As I explained: Your code does not behave as you describe. There is apparently something wrong with your test, not with your code.

Comment: @Flimzy using chrome and different tabs

Comment: @Flimzy different browsers worked, thanks.

Comment: @Flimzy I experience the same when hitting the page in 2 different tabs in Chrome. But as mentioned, this is not an issue of your code but of the way your server is tested.

Comment: I just tested in two Chrome tabs, too, and see the same.  Use different browsers. Chrome is probably sequentializing the reqeusts.

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP server included in the standard library (the one your example uses) handles each incoming requests in a new goroutine, so they run concurrently.

Your app can handle multiple requests concurrently. What you experience is the result of how you test it. Probably you opened your browser and entered `http://localhost:8080/hello` in 2 distinct tabs. It may be your browser's limitation if the same URL is requested and one is in progress, the 2nd is not started. This is what I tried and experienced with Chrome.

But if you open 2 different browsers, e.g. Chrome and Firefox, and visit this page from both of them "at the same time", you'll see `HIT HANDLER` printed twice immediately without seeing `FINISHED` printed.

You get the same result if you open 2 terminals, and execute

```
wget http://localhost:8080/hello
```

in both of them.

Comment: @nightly, Even more enlightening might be to run `for _ in $(seq 1 100); do wget -q http://localhost:8080/hello & done; wait`